# Race condition in Rails 2.3 and phantomJS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, phantomjs

I have a rails 2.3 application running on REE.  I am using capybara 1.1.2, cucumber 1.1.0, poltergeist (used both 0.6.0 and lastest from github) and phantomJS 1.5.0.  My problem is that I believe I have a race condition in phantomJS that is causing my cucumber tests to randomly fail.  The cucumber test work perfectly when I run them in Chrome so I am pretty sure the problem is in poltergeist or phantomJS.  When I run the cucumber tests in PhantomJS (so that I can run them on the CI server) I will randomly get errors like this:

One or more errors were raised in the Javascript code on the page:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function

  http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yd/r/c9z-2BUoufJ.js:75
  http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yd/r/c9z-2BUoufJ.js:75
  http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v2/yd/r/c9z-2BUoufJ.js:9 in bound:(?) (Capybara::Poltergeist::JavascriptError)
./features/step_definitions/site_steps.rb:8:in `/I am on the home page/'
features/account_creation.feature:89:in `Given I am on the home page'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/account_creation.feature:5 # Scenario: I should be able to start creating a resume without signing up
```

cucumber features/account_creation.feature:79 # Scenario: I should be able to log in with an old username and password
    cucumber features/account_creation.feature:88 # Scenario: I should be able to remember my login so that when the browser is closed I am automatically logged in

Based off of the [Github page for poltergeist](https://github.com/jonleighton/poltergeist#important-note-about-rack-versions--130) I have added this to my `env.rb` to solve the rack pre version 1.3 race condition problems:

```
Capybara.server do |app, port|
  require 'rack/handler/thin'
  Thin::Logging.silent = true
  Thin::Server.new('0.0.0.0', port, app).start
end
```

But this has not made any difference that I can tell.  Any thoughts would be appreciated even if it is just a suggesting that this is a poltergeist problem or a phantomJS problem so I know how I should ask about it next.